# AFNetworking - Request method as a parameter

Tags: objective-c, httprequest, afnetworking

I'm seeing in [AFHTTPClient documentation](http://afnetworking.github.io/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#tasks) these pretty tasks for *Making HTTP Requests*:

```
- getPath:parameters:success:failure:
- postPath:parameters:success:failure:
- putPath:parameters:success:failure:
- deletePath:parameters:success:failure:
- patchPath:parameters:success:failure:
```

Now if I need update or create something on my server,
let's say I want to differentiate the update/create by the method:

- create -> PUT
- update -> POST

Would there be a way to specify the method as a parameter somewhere, like:

```
- requestPath:method:parameters:success:failure:
```

Obviously I can create my own dispatcher, but the question is more about why this seems to be done intentionnaly as it is (hoping I'm clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postPath:parameters:success:failure:` is a convenience method for the following:

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/path" parameters:@{...}];
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^{...} failure:^{...}];
  [client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

You can customize any of the objects along the way using the long-form version.